# How to change the step size matplotlib uses when plotting timestamp objects?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm currently attempting to graph a fairly small dataset using the matplotlib and pandas libraries. The format of the dataset is a CSV file. Here is the dataset:

```
DATE,UNRATE
1948-01-01,3.4
1948-02-01,3.8
1948-03-01,4.0
1948-04-01,3.9
1948-05-01,3.5
1948-06-01,3.6
1948-07-01,3.6
1948-08-01,3.9
1948-09-01,3.8
1948-10-01,3.7
1948-11-01,3.8
1948-12-01,4.0
```

I loaded the dataset using pandas (as can be seen, the file that holds that dataset is named 'dataset.csv'):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
dataset['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['DATE'])
```

I then attempted to plot the dataset loaded, using matplotlib:

```
plt.plot(dataset['DATE'], dataset['UNRATE'])
plt.show()
```

The code above mostly worked fine, and displayed the following graph:

[image]

The problem, however, is that *the data I wanted displayed on the x axis, seems to have only been plotted in intervals of two*:

[image]

I found the question, [*Changing the “tick frequency” on x or y axis in matplotlib?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib), which does correlate to my problem. But, from my testing, only seems to work with *integral values*.

I also found the question, [*controlling the number of x ticks in pyplot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188264/controlling-the-number-of-x-ticks-in-pyplot), which seemed to provide a solution to my problem. The method the answer said to use, `to_pydatetime`, was a method of [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). Since my understanding is that [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) would return a `DatetimeIndex` by default, I could use `to_pydatetime` on `dataset['DATE']`:

```
plt.xticks(dataset['DATE'].to_pydatetime())
```

However, I instead received the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'
```

Since this appears to just be default behavior, is there a way to force matplotlib to graph each point along the x axis, rather than simply graphing every other point?

Comment: Nice to see you tinkering with some pandas :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually just started seriously learning it today. As you can see though, I'm not very familiar with the library :-(

Comment: The simplest fix is usually plotting strings (getting datetime out of the equation completely), `dataset['DATE'].astype(str)`

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that worked. Is there any way to avoid having to re-cast `dataset['DATE']` as a `str` though? It seemed best to use the appropriate `dtype` since I _was_ working with dates, but if there's not, I don't think it would be to big of an issue.

Comment: This is the "I don't know any better so this is good enough" fix... hopefully @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest may know a thing or too that I don't. He frequents the mplotlib tag a lot more than anyone else does so hopefully he sees your question.

Comment: Okay, gotcha @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks. For now I can just leave `dataset['DATE']` with a `dtype` of `str`.

Comment: To convert `dataset['DATE']` to a datetime, you need to use `dataset['DATE'].dt.to_pydatetime()` to first convert to a pandas datetime and then to Python!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get rid of the error you may convert the dates as follows and also set the labels accordingly:

```
plt.xticks(dataset['DATE'].tolist(),dataset['DATE'].tolist())
```

or as has been mentionned in the comments

```
plt.xticks(dataset['DATE'].dt.to_pydatetime(),dataset['DATE'].dt.to_pydatetime())
```

[image]

But let's look at some more useful options.

#### Plotting strings

First of all it is possible to plot the data as it is, i.e. as strings.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('dateunrate.txt')
plt.plot(dataset['DATE'], dataset['UNRATE'])

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is just like plotting `plt.plot(["apple", "banana", "cherry"], [1,2,3])`. This means that the successive dates are just placed one-by-one on the axes, independent on whether they are a minute, a day or a year appart. E.g. if your dates were `2018-01-01, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-27` they would still appear equally spaced on the axes.

#### Plot dates with pandas (automatically)

Pandas can nicely plot dates out of the box if the dates are in the index of the dataframe. To this end you may read the dataframe in a way that the first csv column is parsed as the index.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('dateunrate.txt', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
dataset.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is equivalent to

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('../dateunrate.txt', parse_dates=[0])
dataset = dataset.set_index("DATE")
dataset.plot()
```

or

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('../dateunrate.txt')
dataset["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["DATE"])
dataset = dataset.set_index("DATE")
dataset.plot()
```

or even

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('../dateunrate.txt')
dataset["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["DATE"])
dataset.plot(x="DATE",y="UNRATE")
```

This works nice in this case because you happen to have one date per month and pandas will decide to show all 12 months as ticklabels in this case.
For other cases this may result in different tick locations.

#### Plot dates with matplotlib or pandas (manually)

In the general case, you may use `matplotlib.dates` formatters and locators to tweak the tick(label)s in the way you want. Here, we might use a `MonthLocator` and set the ticklabel format to `"%b %Y"`. This works well with matplotlib `plot` or pandas `plot(x_compat=True)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dataset = pd.read_csv('dateunrate.txt', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)

plt.plot(dataset.index, dataset['UNRATE'])
## or use 
#dataset.plot(x_compat=True) #note the x_compat argument

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b %Y"))

plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, these soultions look great!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If I am interested in the step size of 2 months in the x-axis, then?. i.e., I want only Jan, Mar, May, Jul... in the x-axis.